# using swiper in react js app that created by vite

Tags: reactjs, vite

i'am trying to use swiper js in my react js project that created with vite but it throws and error with this title : Failed to resolve import "swiper/css" from "src\components\dashboard-components\Projects.jsx". Does the file exist?
but when i use it in a project that created with create-react-app it works.
what is the problem?

```
    // Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css';

export default () => {
  return (
    <Swiper
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
      onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
      onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      ...
    </Swiper>
  );
};
```